# visual studio source control - create branch for specific folder in VSTS

Tags: c#, wpf, git

I have a Visual Studio project and I want to separate this project by Main Menu Items. Means each menu item should have specific branch and when all works done in it, add this branch to whole project. Can I do it? is this true scenario?

Comment: Are you talking about sub modules?

Comment: @RahulRaut Yes it can be. In detail, I want to create separate branch for each feature and don't let my team's member to access entire project

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea in so many ways.  First of all, are there _any_ interdependencies between the projects?  If so, then one member might need code from another member.  I have never seen such a setup in production anywhere.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right. But what is the way if project is sensitive and I don't want to share whole project to my freelance and temporary team members?

Comment: If the various pieces are completely independent, then there is nothing wrong with using separate repos (I think).  In this case, each contributor just pushes to a different repo.  Submodules are one possibility, but a submodule is still part of its parent repo, so that might not fit your requirement.

Comment: In case of sub modules you need to share code or packages with the team members. As mentioned in above  comments if each module is independent of each other then you can create separate repos for each module. There may be more complicated scenarios when sub modules are getting updated simultaneously. Or there should be one authorised person who will integrate different modules developed by individual developers. That person should have enough business and technical knowledge to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Branches** are different versions of the same code.

**Repositories** are containers for different collections of code. *(Sub-modules are also available but I discourage you from using them until you become proficient with `git`)*

---

### General Adivce

A project should be split into different repositories if and only if there are *really* good reasons to do it; for example security (where team A must not see team B's code).

---

Let's say that you need to need to split the project. 
One way would be as follows:

- Team A works on *repository* A (and inside this repository they have as many branches as they need)
- Team C works on *repository* B
- Team You works on *repository* C which uses code from repo A and repo B.

You still have an important decision to make in this setup. You can share the code via source files or via dlls (e.g. via NuGet).

If you think about about it, this setup, on a large scale, is how .net world works. Team X built a library X.dll and you use NuGet to add it to your project and use it.

Having said this, if it's possible then keep elements of the project together - it makes things easier.